# How to make a Search Bar using React Native with Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, searchbar

I want to make a search bar for searching items from the list using react native with redux

I have tried this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Text, View, FlatList, Image, ScrollView, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import { SearchBox, Spinner } from './common';
import { listShow, searchResult} from './actions';

class flatRedux extends Component {

      componentWillMount() {
          this.props.listShow();     
      }

    _onSearchChange = text => {
        this.props.searchResult(text)
        this.props.listShow(text)
    }

    render() { 
        console.log(this.props);
        return ( 
            <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
             <SearchBox
             placeholder="Search..."
             onChangeText={this._onSearchChange}
              />
                   <FlatList

                      data={this.props.flatlist}

                      ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}

                      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} 

                      renderItem={({item}) =>
                       <Text key={item.id} style={styles.FlatListItemStyle} >
                            {item.cl_name} </Text>}

                     />    
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        search: state.searchResult.search,
        flatlist: state.listShow.flatlist
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { listShow, searchResult })(flatRedux);
```

This is the SearchAction file

```
import { SEARCH_DATA } from './types'
export const searchResult = (text) => {
   return {
     type: SEARCH_DATA,
     payload: text
   };
 }
```

And this one is SearchReducer File

```
import {SEARCH_DATA} from "../actions";

const  INITIAL_STATE = {
  search: ''
}
export default (state =  INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch(action.type) {
    case SEARCH_DATA: 
    return {
      ...state,
      search: action.payload
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And files who are fetching items from the localhost server are below :

flatAction.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { FLAT_DATA } from './types';

export const listShow = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.post('http://192.168.48.228/reactTest/list.php')
          .then((response) => {
            dispatch({ 
              type: FLAT_DATA,
              payload: response.data 
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });  
    };
};
```

flatReducer.js

```
import {FLAT_DATA } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    flatlist: '',
};
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FLAT_DATA:
            return { ...state, flatlist: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }      
};
```

All items are fetching but 'Search' is not working for them.

Comment: So, I remember to used this some time ago. Look at this repo https://github.com/ianvasco/ReactNative-SimpleForm
I can't post an answer right now. Hope it helps

Comment: @Ian Steban Vasco, no problem...I can wait till tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

> 'Search' is not working for them?

it's not detailed enough to give a specific answer.

To debug the workflow try changing the endpoint of `listShow` to `search` and then calling  `this.props.listShow(text)` on input `onChange` handler the see if the redux part is properly connected

assuming,

> All items are fetching

If it is not working need to see if your `keyListners` are working or not (need to see the code for searchbox), and finally, if the `flatlist` is rerendered (It doesn't rerender if **shallow comparison** fails)